# How to jitter contingency table while keeping the marginals constant in R?

Tags: r, contingency, xtabs

If there is a `data.frame` with two factors:

```
tbl = data.frame(Cols = c(rep('A', 300), rep('B', 350), rep('C', 300)),
                 Rows = c(rep('X', 100), rep('Y', 100), rep('Z', 100),
                          rep('X', 125), rep('Y', 100), rep('Z', 125),
                          rep('X', 100), rep('Y', 100), rep('Z', 100)))
head(tbl)
#   Cols Rows
# 1    A    X
# 2    A    X
# 3    A    X
# 4    A    X
# 5    A    X
# 6    A    X
```

we can create a 2-way contingency table:

```
crosstbl = xtabs(~ Rows + Cols, data=tbl)
crosstbl
#     Cols
# Rows   A   B   C
#    X 100 125 100
#    Y 100 100 100
#    Z 100 125 100
```

What would be an efficient way to introduce some random changes in that table, like `jitter()`, while keeping the marginals constant? For example:

```
jittered_crosstbl
#     Cols
# Rows   A   B   C
#    X 110 120  95
#    Y 100 115  85
#    Z  90 115 120
```

Potentially, many such tables are needed with these random "fluctuations".

Comment: Do you want it by row or column

Comment: You can use `sample`, `runif`, `rnorm`,..., combined `floor` or `ceiling`. I can't see the problem. Perhaps a more detailed explanation could help.

Comment: @akrun Both are matching to the original table